# Vertex Weight Proximity Not Controlling Hair Particle Density

Tags: hair, vertex-weights

In a scene, I have a Grid with hair particles growing out of it. The grid is a very large grassy field, so I want only the hairs close to the camera to render.

A sphere is parented to the camera, and the Weight Proximity modifier uses it as a target.

The vertex weights work fine with "Length" of the hair, but won't change the "Density."

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!**
When applying said modifier, enable "Use Modifier Stack" (found under the Emission section in the Particle tab)